# Tkinter bind method not working because of focus in entry on previous frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Tkinter GUI made of multiple frames.

In Frame 1 there are 3 entries and 1 button. The entries set string values to some variables and the button makes Frame 2 appear.
In Frame 2 there are 1 label and 1 button. The button closes the program.

In Frame 2 i have 2 bind methods. I need to start a function when Mouse-Button-1 (left click) is pressed, and another one when Escape is pressed.

The problem is that if I fill the entries (in Frame 1), the Escape key press doesn't work, but Mouse-Button-1 does (in Frame 2). If I do not fill the entries, everything works fine.

I know it's a problem of focus. When i fill the entries, they get the focus, but if I do not fill them, when Frame 2 appears, it gets the focus and the Escape key works fine.

`self.focus_set()` method in Frame 2 is what makes the Mouse-Button-1 work: in fact, if I do not use this method, even this key binding doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```py
from tkinter import *

def keyf1(Event):
    print("function 1")

def keyf2(Event):
    print("function 2")

def start(Event):
    global nometopo
    global classetopo
    global sessione

    nometopo = entry_nome.get()
    classetopo = entry_classe.get()
    sessione = entry_sessione.get()

    entry_nome.delete(0, 'end')
    entry_classe.delete(0, 'end')
    entry_sessione.delete(0, 'end')


class EPMouse(Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (Frame_1, Frame_2):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(Frame_1)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class Frame_1(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        global entry_nome
        global entry_classe
        global entry_sessione

        label_nome=Label(self,text="Nome soggetto: ").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E)
        label_classe=Label(self,text="Classificato come: ").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=E)
        label_sessione=Label(self,text="Sessione: ").grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=E)

        entry_nome = Entry(self)
        entry_nome.grid(row=2,column=1)
        entry_classe = Entry(self)
        entry_classe.grid(row=3,column=1)
        entry_sessione = Entry(self)
        entry_sessione.grid(row=5,column=1)

        button_start = Button(self, text="START!", command=lambda: [start(Event), controller.show_frame(Frame_2)]).grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=EW)

class Frame_2(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        global label

        label_header = Label(self, text="Click sx = F1 \n Esc = F2").pack()

        button_stop = Button(self, text="STOP", command=lambda: app.destroy()).pack()

        self.bind("<Button-1>", keyf1)
        self.bind("<Escape>", keyf2)
        self.focus_set()

app = EPMouse()
app.mainloop()
```

Maybe I need to get the focus out of the entry in Frame 1, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your problem is very simple. Just bring the *frame 2* in focus when you raise it.

Here I can see that you're using this function to switch the frames so why not add one more line to solve the focus issues.

```
def show_frame(self, cont):
    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()
    frame.focus_set()
```

See it was that simple.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm stoked by the simplicity of the solution, but I have to admit I would have never thought to do this alone. In fact, i thought that the focus.set() method in Frame 2 was all I could do.
Very helpful and clean!